# C# Visual Studio 2015 using Math.Pow gives different outputs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math, pow

I have a complete strange problem with my friend's code. Here is the code:

```
double Wampr = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxWampr.Text); //39437
double Vmax = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxVmax.Text); // 295
double Nrdte = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxNrdte.Text); //5
double Nstatic = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxNstatic.Text); //2
double CEF = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxCEF.Text); //3.1
double Fdiff = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxFdiff.Text); //1.8
double Fobs = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxFobs.Text); //1


double output = 0.001244 * Math.Pow(Wampr, 1.160) * Math.Pow(Vmax, 1.371) * Math.Pow(Nrdte - Nstatic, 1.281)* CEF * Fdiff * Fobs;

textbox1.Text = output.ToString();
```

It supposed to calculate and the result is `14791812.0609327`

Unfortunately, in his lappy, the outcome become `1479181206.09327`

See the difference? the decimal places.

I have tested it in a few laptops and the result is good (right answer, the first one) but not in his laptop, the result is the second one (`1479181206.09327`)

I've try to run a few test to run in his Visual Studio, for example:

```
double output = 14791812.060932;
textbox1.Text = output.ToString();
```

and it run smoothly without any error/strange result.

So I think its because of Math.Pow. What do you think about this problem?

Thanks in advance.

I update the code with the value that supposed to be filled inside the text box at the end of the code.

~I try to put the value directly to the equation and the result is correct. So its not Math.Pow problem.

Comment: Try with `decimal`. It was suggested many times, ( from what I know ) it's more precise than `double`.

Comment: Could you show the values of each variable?

Comment: could you make the title a little less generic? It will really help the experts related to the issue find your question

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew, I edit the code above

Comment: Debugging should show which value is parsed differently than you expect. Much smaller test case should be `Console.Write(double.Parse ("1.1"))`. I assume after you see 11 as output on your friends laptop you will be able to track down they region settings (which would be different from yours)

Comment: yeah..thats the answer cultureinfo